# Print RichTextBox text that is longer than one page?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I've got the following code, and looked at as many similar questions on here and google, but all solutions have the same flaw, when the content in the RTB is longer than one page, or more than one or two lines, it prints an infinite number of pages. What should be changed to only print the correct number of pages?

```
private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainTabSet.TabCount > 0)
        {
            RichTextBox textbox = (RichTextBox)MainTabSet.SelectedTab.Controls["TabTextBox"];
            PrintDocument docToPrint = new PrintDocument();
            docToPrint.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPageHandler);
            docToPrint.DocumentName = MainTabSet.SelectedTab.Text;
            PrintDialog.Document = docToPrint;

            if(PrintDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                docToPrint.Print();
            }

        }
    }

    private void PrintPageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainTabSet.TabCount > 0)
        {
            RichTextBox textbox = (RichTextBox)MainTabSet.SelectedTab.Controls["TabTextBox"];
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(textbox.Text);
            float linesPerPage = 0.0f;
            float yPosition = 0.0f;
            int count = 0;
            float leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
            float rightMargin = e.MarginBounds.Right;
            float topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
            string line = null;
            Font printFont = textbox.Font; //maybe do selection font
            SolidBrush printBrush = new SolidBrush(textbox.ForeColor);//Maybe do selection color
            int charPos = 0;
            int xPosition = (int)leftMargin;

            linesPerPage = e.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics);

            while (count < linesPerPage && ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
            {
                xPosition = (int)leftMargin;
                yPosition = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
                count++;
                for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                {
                    textbox.Select(charPos, 1);
                    if ((xPosition + ((int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(textbox.SelectedText, textbox.SelectionFont).Width)) > rightMargin)
                    {
                        count++;
                        if (!(count < linesPerPage))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        xPosition = (int)leftMargin;
                        yPosition = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
                    }
                    printBrush = new SolidBrush(textbox.SelectionColor);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(textbox.SelectedText, textbox.SelectionFont, printBrush, new PointF(xPosition, yPosition));
                    xPosition += ((int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(textbox.SelectedText, textbox.SelectionFont).Width);
                    charPos++;
                }
            }

            if (line != null)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.HasMorePages = false;
                printBrush.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help.
//Nodnarb3

Comment: You need a variable that is external to your handler to keep track of where you are line wise in your richtextbox, everytime you print a new page you retrigger your handler causing all of your variable to be reset which is giving you your endless loop. You have a lot of other issues in your code that you need to address. FYI next time you post a code snippit please make sure it will run as is without use needing to try to recreate your entire application.

Comment: Here is the [MSDN solution](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;812425) which includes the formatting!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in PrintPageHandler

```
private void PrintPageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{

    int charactersOnPage = 0;
    int linesPerPage = 0;

    // Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters 
    // of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
    e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, font1,
        e.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
        out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

    // Draws the string within the bounds of the page
    e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, font1, Brushes.Black,
        e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

    // Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
    stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage);

    // Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
    e.HasMorePages = (stringToPrint.Length > 0);
}
```

And the PrintButton Code

```
   private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stringToPrint = tabsProperties[tabsProperties.IndexOf(new TabProperties(this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex))].TabHtml;

        printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        printDocument1.Print();

    }
```